# Add each element of matrix A to matrix B that result in an expanded matrix of A

Tags: matlab

I would like to add each element of matrix `A` to matrix `B` and have an expanded matrix `A` that is the new matrix `C`.

```
A = [1 2 3]

B =  
[10 20  
20 30]
```

Required result matrix 2x6:

```
C =  
[11 12 13 21 22 23;  
 21 22 23 31 32 33]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one using [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
reshape(bsxfun(@plus, permute(B,[1,3,2]), A),size(B,1),[])
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2     3
>> B
B =
    10    20
    20    30
>> reshape(bsxfun(@plus, permute(B,[1,3,2]), A),size(B,1),[])
ans =
    11    12    13    21    22    23
    21    22    23    31    32    33
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Div.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand `A` and `B` to the correct size using [`kron`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) and then just add them together:

```
>> A2 = kron(A, ones(2, 2))

A2 =

   1   1   2   2   3   3
   1   1   2   2   3   3

>> B2 = kron(B, (1, 3))

B2 =

   10   10   10   20   20   20
   20   20   20   30   30   30

>> C = A2 + B2

C =

   11   11   12   22   23   23
   21   21   22   32   33   33
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
C = kron(A, ones(2, 2)) + kron(B, ones(1, 3))
```

If the sizes of `A` and `B` are variable, you can do something like

```
C = kron(A, ones(size(B))) + kron(B, ones(size(A)))
```

The properties of the Kronecker product guarantee that this will always work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback Mad Physicist.  Your and @Divakar resulting matrix C differs unfortunately a bit from my matrix C. Sorry I see Divakar had it correct, my bad.

Comment: @Cysthius. I see what you mean. I didn't expand A correctly. Will fix when I get to a computer.

Comment: No problem @Mad, thanks again for the assistance in any case.